# Understanding dispatchEvent(evt.clone())

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am kind of new to action script and trying to understand an existing code. Here I have the MyRestServiceEvent and MyRestService. There are many methods defined in MyRestService class that dispach many events but some implement `dispatchEvent(evt.clone());` which I cannot understand. I know MyRestServiceEvent has already implemented the clone(), so what does this `dispatchEvent(evt.clone());` do? I truly appreciate if someone could explain me the process.

Below is a little snapsht of those two classes.

> the event class

```
        public function MyRestServiceEvent(type:String, request:MyRestRequest, result:* = null, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

            this.result = result;
            this.request = request;
        }

        /**
         * Override clone to support re-dispatching
         */
        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new MyRestServiceEvent(type, this.request, this.result, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

> the event dispatcher class

```
public class MyRestService extends EventDispatcher
    {

        // ton of methods here but below is an example of one of the functions 

        private function checkAdminErrorHandler(evt:MyRestServiceEvent):void
        {
            dispatchEvent(evt.clone());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `clone()` method creates a duplicate instance of the Event object. It does so by creating a fresh instance of the class and setting its properties to the same values as the original instance. Custom events may override this method to handle the replication of reference types correctly.

Cloning is required when an event is to be redispatched, so that its read-only properties (bubbles, cancelable, currentTarget, target) can be set again to new values.

Comment: I think that you explained the definition of the `clone()` method that should be declared in the event class. However, I wanted to know why it's being cloned again in `dispatchEvent(evt.clone())`. In other words what would happen by dispatching the cloned event again.

Answer (score 2):

The clone in your code example is completely redundant - dispatchEvent actually dispatches a clone (hence the need for [overriding] the clone method in custom Events) so there's no need to pass it a clone. This code would work exactly the same:

```
dispatchEvent(evt);
```

As to why the event is being redispatched, i would guess that its because Event bubbling is set to false. So redispatching the Event effectively 'bubbles' it up another layer in the application so more 'stuff' can listen for it.